# SQL Server Alter Table Query (Incorrect Syntax)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stumped, and I know this is probably something very simple. I am trying to add two columns to an existing table.

I am receiving the following syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'PublishedDate' Expecting '(', or SELECT.

Here is my SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (PublishedDate DATETIME, UnpublishedDate DATETIME)
```

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275621(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try without the parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD PublishedDate DATETIME, UnpublishedDate DATETIME
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75be9/1) with a demo for you to try.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I knew it was going to be something right in front of my face